# Issue in saving the multiselect dropdown values

Tags: magento-1.9

I had created the new field of multi select dropdown the values are getting selected but they are not saving in DB.

I had created the column in table.

SQL Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `mg_hospital` ADD `specilaities` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ;
```

Can you please suggest how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a form  with multiselect field have submit data then it send it field value to array. So on `saveAction` function you need to translate fields value to string

Goes to `saveAction`

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

I simply added the following code:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $data[$key] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam($key)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is SQL query is correct to save the multiple values

Comment: no..never.It too bad idea

Comment: can u please specify the query.so i can change and test

Comment: Can u please give the sql query

Comment: Busy now..see later